# Setting HBase Properties for Particular session

Tags: hive, hbase

I have a scenario I need to increase `hbase.client.scanner.caching to 10000 from 100`. But I don't want to make this permanent change, I only need it for that particular session when I am querying from hive querying engine. Is there any way how to set this property for that particular session.

i.e 
`set hbase.client.scanner.caching = 10000;` 
`SELECT count(*) FROM hive_external_table;` 
-- but  setting the parameter is not taking any effect. 
-- where hive_external_table is a external table mapped from hbase_table

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you can definitely set the property value in the same way. Don't give whitespace between `key=value`.

Use following:

```
hive> set hbase.client.scanner.caching=10000;
hive> SELECT count(*) FROM hive_external_table;
```

It will override the default value for the current session.